# ProcessCmdKey vs ProcessDialogKey

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and I detect when enter key is pressed for validate/commit cell's value. I detect this key in `ProcessCmdKey` but I know exists another similar method called `ProcessDialogKey` so which is the difference between them? What happens if I use `ProcessCmdKey` for detecting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> keys instead of using `ProcessDialogKey`?

Also, I have a little problem in my application, I have associated the delete key to delete the current selected items in a tree winforms component but this event is raised when I am in edit mode in a `DataGridView`'s cell and I press delete key. So I would like to handle this key if a `DataGridView`'s cell is currently in edit mode and user press delete key in order to avoid to raise the event that deletes the selected items in the tree. So how to achieve this? Can I use `ProcessCmdKey` to detect delete key and if so, consume it? Should it work?

Answer (score 1):

To validate a row in `DataGridView`, you should be using [`RowValidating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating.aspx) event, this would save you from all the quirks in `ProcessCmdKey`. It will also take care of validation if you leave the row by using a mouse, up/down arrow, or page up/down.

Regarding `TreeView`, you should better use `KeyDown` event. Without any additional steps, it will only be triggered if `TreeView` is focused. If you are working inside a `DataGridView` - it will not fire. That is, <kbd>Del</kbd> key will delete text when in `Edit` mode, delete rows when row is selected, and do nothing if sitting on the cell. This is default behavior of the controls in question - no extra code is required to make it work like that.

You should avoid overriding `ProcessCmdKey` unless it does not work otherwise (which is rare cases).

Comment: I have seen some of those rare cases, like hitting enter in a 3rd party grid causing the dialog to close (AcceptButton set) and doesn't accept the value.  Using ProcessCmdKey allowed me to check if Enter was pressed and there was a valid ActiveCell, then save the value into the property before the dialog close.  This is just some extra info, your post is very much true, but ProcessCmdKey can come in handy when components are causing headaches.